# Angular animations with query not keeping state

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm trying to do a mouseover animation with Angular 5 Animations module. So far I manage to bind the mouse enter and mouse leave events and trigger the animation, but can't manage to keep the hover state while the mouse is still hovering the element. It's seams to trigger the animation and immediately after finishing the animation it rolls back to initial state.

Here is an example of the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7xvqsr

Am I missing anything here? Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I've managed to solve it by switching to state instead of query function.
Here's my solution in case of anyone having the same difficulty:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xz5whd

Thanks to myself,
Happy coding.

Comment: I am have the same problem. This isn't really "the" solution since sometimes query is required.